# How to erase one region in Excel when closing the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, erase

I have a spreadsheet, with whatever in it. Now I want use one specific region (let's say C1:D10) to hold temporary data (in case I cannot remember clearly or mess them up).

However, I don't want keep the data  for ever, and it is totally useless when this spreadsheet is used next time. Is there any way to erase this part when the spreadsheet is closed, no matter whether the user choose "save the change" or not, so that (C1:D10) is blank when I open the spreadsheet next time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of clearing the cells upon exit, use the `Workbook_Open` to clear the cells. This way you don't need to bother whether the user save the workbook on exit or not. This code will clear the cell the moment the workbook is opened.

Change `Sheet1` below to the relevant sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:D10").ClearContents
End Sub
```